# How can I combine generic iterator-based algorithms with implementation based algorithms?

Tags: c++, templates

I am using the Strategy Pattern, together with the Abstract Factory Pattern to generate different algorithms in a Calculator class during run-time.

The calculations will depend on a Relationship between involved types. This is why I made  the "*Algorithm::calculate" a member function template, generic with respect to a Relationship.

However, I already have an algorithm that is completely implementation-based in the existing code, it is not-generic nor iterator-based, and I want to add it to the algorithm hierarchy so that I can produce it using the AbstractFactory as well and see how it behaves.

An implemenation based algorithm uses the member functions of the types involved in the calculations to get the calculation done. In this example, it would use RelationshipWithA::target_type member functions to access the data of the Type&, as well as "A" member functions to access the data of RelationshipWithA::a_.

This is what I came up with so far (this is just a model, without the Abstract Factory, and the Calculator class):

```
#include <iostream>

class Result{}; 

class A {};  

class B {
    public: 
        void specific() const 
        { 
            std::cout << "B::specific()" << std::endl;
        };
};

class C : public B {};

class D {};

template<class Type>
class RelationshipWithA
{
    const A& a_; 

    const Type& t_;

    public: 
        typedef Type target_type; 

        RelationshipWithA (const A& a, const Type& t)
            :
                a_(a), 
                t_(t)

        {
            std::cout << "RelationshipWithA::ctor" << std::endl;
        }; 

        const A& a() const 
        {
            return a_; 
        }

        const Type& type() const
        {
            return t_;
        }
};

class DefaultAlgorithm 
{
    public:
        template <class Relationship>
        void calculate (Result& res, const Relationship& r)
        {
            std::cout << "DefaultAlgorithm::calculate" << std::endl;
            const A& a = r.a(); 
            const typename Relationship::target_type& t = r.type(); 
            // Default iterator based calculation on a, target_type and r
        };
};

class AlternativeAlgorithm 
: 
    public DefaultAlgorithm 
{
    public:
        template <class Relationship>
        void calculate (Result& res, const Relationship& r)
        {
            std::cout << "AlternativeAlgorithm::calculate" << std::endl;
            // Optimized iterator based calculation on a, target_type and r
        }
};

class ImplementationBasedAlgorithm 
:
    public DefaultAlgorithm 
{
    public:
        // No specialization: Relationships store
        // a const reference to any class that inherits from B
        template <class Relationship>
        void calculate (Result& res, const Relationship& r)
        {
            // Use B implementation and the Relationship With  A to compute the result
            std::cout << "ImplementationBasedAlgorithm::calculate" << std::endl;
            const A& a = r.a(); 
            const B& b = r.type();
            b.specific();
            // Implementation based on B implementation
        }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    Result res; 

    A a; 
    C c; 

    RelationshipWithA<C> relationshipAC (a, c);

    DefaultAlgorithm defaultAlg; 
    AlternativeAlgorithm alternativeAlg;
    ImplementationBasedAlgorithm implementationAlg;

    defaultAlg.calculate(res, relationshipAC);
    alternativeAlg.calculate(res, relationshipAC);
    implementationAlg.calculate(res,relationshipAC);

    D d; 
    RelationshipWithA<D> relationshipAD (a, d);

    defaultAlg.calculate(res, relationshipAD);
    alternativeAlg.calculate(res, relationshipAD);
    // This fails, as expected
    //implementationAlg.calculate(res,relationshipAD);

    return 0;
}
```

I like this design because the algorithms are not generic classes, which makes it easy for the Generic Abstract Factory to produce them during run-time.

However, in Effective C++ there is an Item 36 saying: "never redefine an inherited non-virtual function". I mean, non-virtual functions are implementation invariant, they should not be overriden in general, but:

1. There are no virtual member function templates available in C++.
2. If I make the Algorithm classes generic on RelationshipWithA and "*Algorithm::calculate" a vritual member function, the Factory needs to know about the Realtionship in order to generate Algorithms, and the code gets seriously smelly (to me at least).

Is this then a proper solution for the problem, even though I override inherited non-virtual functions (function templates)?

To the client, there is no difference in behaviour what so ever: the result is there, the only difference is in the way it is computed. This means that the Is-A relationship is still upheld: the "*Algorithm::calculate" is still implementation invariant to the client.

Comment: What is an "implementation based algorithm"?

Comment: @CrisStringfellow as you see in the ImplementationBasedAlgorithm, its implementation is not using iterators, it's using B member functions directly: "B::specific()", which makes this algorithm useable only with RelationshipWithA which is templated with a class that inherits from B, such as C. However, I want the algorithms to work on separate types as well (for example, D), and since D is not inheriting from B, the ImplementationBasedAlgorithm will not compile. Actually, A, B and D are very complex types (but similar) comming from different libraries so I save code with generic algorithms.

Comment: @CrisStringfellow the fact that the ImplementationBasedAlgorithm doesn't compile for D is *good*, this is what I want, the only problem here is that I am overriding non-virtual member function (templates), so I need to know if this is a standard practice in production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't really an **Is-A** relationship...

The specific implementations aren't really **A DefaultAlgorithm**... they are specific algorithms...

You could have an empty `BaseAlgorithm` class that you can create with the factory. But then you'll need to cast it to the right type anyway before using the template functions. This kinda beats the factory pattern anyway, because you aren't using an interface.

In your case if the factory creates one of the derived classes but returns the base class, if you use that variable, it will call the base class methods:

```
DefaultAlgorithm algo = Factory.CreateImplementationBasedAlgorithm();
RelationshipWithA<D> relationshipAD (a, d);
algo.calculate(res, relationshipAD); //won't fail because the base class methods are used (because it isn't virtual)
```

To fix that, you could make the a base `Relationship` class, and make the **calculate()** method virtual.
The **calculate()** method will get then you could static_cast the Relationship to some base_relationship interface that has the interface you want for that algorithm, and so you can achive the compilation failure for not having the right **a()** or **type()** methods.

Comment: I get what you mean, thanks! :) However, how can I make the Relationship a base class for completely two separate Type classes (B + inherited classes, D)? I mean, there is nothing in common between the derived classes of Relationship in that case, nothing to put in the Relationship base class. And the relationship itself is computed in a generic way.. within Relationship.

Comment: What's your goal ? are you trying to make a **list<BaseAlgorithm>** that will hold different algorithms ?

Comment: yes the Calculator has a set of algorithms, but not stored in a container (like a list), they are defined as its member functions. The problem is that the algorithms are generic.  I think I'll drop the factory and run-time selection, and just use templates. This means re-compiling a single client for a different implementation of the same algorithm, which will cause some pain during benchmarking/testing, but once I see which algorithm works best, I will keep the algorithm choice fixed anyway I guess..